# Oracle 18 - How can I add additional components to an existing client installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

When you first install Oracle Client, there are numerous checkboxes for various components.

[image]

Once you have installed Oracle Client, how can you go back an select additional components you didn't check originally?  (In my case, the Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server.)  Or do you have to uninstall and re-install?

Comment: No need uninstall. You simply run the installer again, select your existing home, and check more boxes. It'll add what you check that isn't there already.

Comment: @PaulW - Thanks.  Why not put that as the answer instead of a comment.